# Virtual Composer: How to horizontally align contents from two different columns?

Tags: columns, design

First of all, I have never used this site before, so I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this particular question.

I am trying to build a website using virtual composer.
Right now I have two different columns: the left column contains several icons and the right side contains several pieces of texts. The amount of text blocks is equal to the amount of logos. I am trying to horizontally align each icon with its corrosponding text block, but I can't figure out how to do this. Is there somebody who could help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the items in one visual composer row that has two columns.

Since the icon heights are probably higher than the default line height, the easiest and in my opinion cleanest solution would be to break each icon & text into separate visual composer rows. You can also nest a row inside of another row in visual composer. (IE: a Parent row that holds all the child rows inside of it.)

Once you have the rows all setup, check the settings for the rows. Depending on your version of Visual Composer there might be an option to "align row content". Normally the options for this are "top, middle, bottom".

Comment: Yesss! that did the trick!
Thanks for the detailed explanation!